# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to lock a critical section by a key (string)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, locking, mutex

Attempt:

```
public class KeyLock : IDisposable
{
    private string key; 

    private static ISet<string> lockedKeys = new HashSet<string>();

    private static object locker1 = new object();

    private static object locker2 = new object();

    public KeyLock(string key)
    {
        lock(locker2)
        {
           // wait for key to be freed up
           while(lockedKeys.Contains(key));

           this.lockedKeys.Add(this.key = key);     
        }
    } 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock(locker)
        {
            lockedKeys.Remove(this.key);
        }
    }
}
```

to be used like

```
using(new KeyLock(str))
{
    // section that is critical based on str
}
```

I test by firing the method twice in the same timespan

```
private async Task DoStuffAsync(string str)
{
    using(new KeyLock(str))
    {
       await Task.Delay(1000);
    }         
}

// ...

await Task.WhenAll(DoStuffAsync("foo"), DoStuffAsync("foo"))
```

but, strangely enough, when I debug I see that the second time it goes straight through the `lock` and in fact somehow `lockedKeys.Contains(key)` evaluates to `false` even through I can see in my debugger windows that the key is there.

Where is the flaw and how do I fix it?

Comment: You must use the same lock object for both sections.

Comment: @Enigmativity Do you not find having an infinite loop in the constructor a bit dangerous

Comment: @Enigmativity - locking and then waiting for a state to change which can only be changed by another thread acquiring the same lock looks equally problematic. User7127000 - can you take a step back and tell us what *problem* you have that you created this class to try to solve? Because I'm not sure it's that salvageable from its current state.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - Sorry, I missed that. Wow. That's a huge problem. My rule is allow constructors to complete and complete quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [lock statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

It basically breaks down to

```
object __lockObj = x;
bool __lockWasTaken = false;
try
{
    System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(__lockObj, ref __lockWasTaken);
    // Your code...
}
finally
{
    if (__lockWasTaken) System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(__lockObj);
}
```

[Enter(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Monitor_Enter_System_Object_)

> Acquires an exclusive lock on the **specified** **object**.

---

What you need to do instead, is keep around and obtain the same reference. You could probably use a thread safe Dictionary `ConcurrentDictionary`

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> LockMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> ();

...

lock (LockMap.GetOrAdd(str, x => new object ()))
{
    // do locky stuff
}
```

***Note*** : This is just one example of many ways to do this, you will obviously need to tweak it for your needs

Answer (score 0):

The main problems that I notice are as follows:

※Super dangerous infinite loop in the constructor, and super wasteful as well.
※When accessing the private field `lockedKeys`, you use different objects to lock on→ Not good

However, why your code does not seem to be working I think is because of the short delay you set. Since it is only 1 second of delay during the debugging when you step from statement to statement, 1 second already passes and it gets disposed.

```
using(new KeyLock(str)){
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Luckily for you, I came across a similar problem before and I have a solution, too. Look [here](https://github.com/emrahsungu/Hes.Synchronization/blob/master/Hes.Synchronization/AsyncLock.cs) for my small solution.

Usage:

```
//Resource to be shared
private AsyncLock _asyncLock = new AsyncLock();
....
....
private async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    using(await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }         
} 

// ...

await Task.WhenAll(DoStuffAsync(), DoStuffAsync())
```

Comment: `You create a new KeyLock instance but the moment await comes, KeyLock instance is disposed immediately.` That's wrong. `KeyLock` will be disposed only after `Task.Delay` is done executing

Comment: @KevinGosse, I stand corrected. It looks like I was under the impression that as soon as the await operator is hit the using block will also be disposed.